Unknown movie about invasive alien entity creature
This movie is only by a couple scenes I think back on and have been searching for.
We are out on the ocean, on an ocean liner, a science vessel, or other ship of some kind.  There is an unusual looking alien specimen, or sea creature being held within a metal compartment, in a glass tank or something.  The guy opens the metal door, turning away to some science equipment, etc....but hears the creature stir behind the glass.  He turns around and eases close to the glass gazing into the tank at the entity.  After a silent pause, the creature explodes through the glass, slamming him against the other wall, and plasters him up against the wall, under it.  Kinda a transparent material, with lots of tendrils (I think).
At the end, I think the man is possessed by the creature, and with his body doused with fire...he steps over the edge of the ship, and leaving the ship burning behind...disappears into the ocean, beneath the waves in the night.

80's movie alien

More Aliens than Alien, but that's the first I thought of as well.

@LloydCantuII: Was it Alien?

Sounds like my kind of movie... Has anyone found out what it is?

Could it possibly be Deep Rising (1998)?
Set in an oceanic scenario with a ship

The film opens with an explanation about deep water trenches with
  undiscovered sea life. A boat is being piloted through a storm on the
  South China Sea by John Finnegan (Treat Williams). With him are his
  crewmen Joey "Tooch" Pantucci (Kevin J. O'Connor), and Joey's
  girlfriend Leila (Una Damon). Finnegan has been hired to lead a group
  of mercenaries to an undisclosed location in the middle of the ocean.
  The mercenaries are: Hanover (Wes Studi), Vivo (Djimon Hounsou), Mason
  (Clifton Powell), Mulligan (Jason Flemyng), Billy (Clint Curtis),
  T-Ray (Trevor Goddard), and Mamooli (Cliff Curtis).

Creature with tentacles

Canton and Atherton explain creatures attacked the ship and killed
  everyone else on board; the group soon discovers human skeletons
  stripped clean of flesh in the bottom of the ship. After questioning
  Canton is also revealed to be the saboteur; he hired the mercenaries
  to destroy the ship so he could collect on the insurance, due to badly
  misplaying with the market and having to pay 400 million dollars for
  the ship. The group is suddenly attacked by giant tentacles, and
  Captain Atherton is killed. The remaining survivors agree to work
  together to escape. Canton theorizes that the tentacles are from
  evolved deep-sea worms which strip their prey of body fluids and then
  eject the carcass.

Ends with fire

They see an island in the distance, but it is too far to travel
  without engines. Finnegan tells Joey to set the boat on autopilot and
  crash it into the Argonautica to detonate the mercenaries' torpedoes,
  which are still on his boat, and destroy the creature. Finnegan
  returns to the ship to find Trillian and get a jet ski from the cargo
  bay. Canton tries to kill Trillian so there are no witnesses to his
  scheme, but Finnegan saves her and Canton flees back into the ship.
  The creature pulls itself out of the water in full, revealing itself
  as a kraken and attacks the two, but they escape. Finnegan returns to
  his boat to find Joey gone with evidence of another attack. Finnegan
  sets the boat's autopilot and leaves on the jet ski with Trillian.
  Canton climbs on board, but cannot turn off the autopilot, so the boat
  rams the Argonautica and explodes, killing the creature and Canton.

I also thought of The Abyss (1989) but it didn't fit with the creature.

By any chance, are you talking about this movie?  The Thing (1982) .
Plot :

Scientists in the Antarctic are confronted by a shape-shifting alien that assumes the appearance of the people that it kills.

Although I have not seen the 1982 movie but I've seen this one The Thing (2011)  a remake of the older one and it kinda matches your description but there's no ocean liner in this movie. Good Luck.

Really far fetched, but from the plot description: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lords_of_the_Deep ?
